# delay in animation after several calls using jquery.animate

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, delayed-execution

I am trying to show overlay all over the page after click on div by calling function that implements jquery.animate in a click event
what is happening after several click say like 4 or 5 tries I begin to note there is a delay between clicking the div and the overlay showing itself and this delay is getting increased after every click

a detailed code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/muhammadelmogy/3u9qjLuc/1/) and here is the javascript code

```
function initTemplateEditor(params) {
if (typeof params === "undefined") {
    throw new Error("can't init the editor without params!");
}

var
openEditor = function () {
    $(params.templateEditor).animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, {
        duration: 350,
        start: function () {
            $(params.templateEditor).css({
                "display": "block",
                    "width": $(window).width() - 10,
                    "height": $(window).height() - 10
            });
        }
    });
},
closeEditor = function () {
    $(params.templateEditor).animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 350, function () {
        $(this).css("display", "none");
    });
};
$("#editorClose").click(function () {
    closeEditor();
});
openEditor();
}

$(".template-box").click(function () {
    initTemplateEditor({
        templateEditor: "#templateEditor",
        template: this
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time you call `initTemplateEditor`, you're adding to the `editorClose` click chain with this function:

```
$("#editorClose").click(function () {
    closeEditor();
});
```

If you add an `alert` inside the function, you'll see it's being called once the first time, twice the second time, etc.

Add this line of code immediately before that `click` function, and it should solve your problem:

```
$("#editorClose").unbind("click");
```